# Spring boot service not executing deleteBy from repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpql

I'm doing a sort of a feed with posts and comments 
**Post entity**

```
public class Post extends AuditEntity {
    @Lob
    private String text;

    @Column
    private int totalCmnts = 0;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Set<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MEUser MEUser;

}
```

**Comment entity**

```
public class Comment extends AuditEntity {
        @Lob
        private String text;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private MEUser MEUser;
    
}
```

and i have a service to delete a comment where i fetch the post and the comment, i check if the current user can execute the operation then i delete the comment and decrement the total count of comments in post entity.

the problem in the log i can see the select operation and the update operation but the delet  is not executed at all and still getting HTTP 200 with @transactional annotation in the service class

I tried an SQL query and it worked fine

```
DELETE FROM `db-engine`.comment WHERE comment.id = 2
```

Service

```
@Override
public void deleteComment(Long commentID, Long postID, UserPrincipal currentUser) {
    Comment comment = commentsRepository.findById(commentID)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    Post post = postsRepository.findById(postID)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    if (comment.getMEUser().getId().equals(currentUser.getId())
            || currentUser.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN.toString()))
            || currentUser.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleName.ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN.toString()))) {

        commentsRepository.deleteById(comment.getId());
        post.setTotalCmnts(post.getTotalCmnts() - 1);
        System.out.println(comment.getId());
        System.out.println("hello");

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly deleting the Comment by the CommentsRepository, remove the Comment from the `comments` collection of the Post entity. When JPA flushes at the end of the transaction, it will delete the row from the `comment` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are changing the `post` entity with `post.setTotalCmnts(post.getTotalCmnts() - 1);`. This means that Hibernate will notice the difference between your entity and the data in database and flush it (thus updating the `post` in the database).
Since you have `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` on `comments` this means that Hibernate will cascade the persist operation to `comments` entities. In this list, you still have the `Comment` you want to delete and thus it is created again (there might be some Hibernate optimization here that understands this and actually does not delete it from the database instead).

You need to also remove the `Comment` you want to delete from the `post` `comments` list as follows:

```java
commentsRepository.deleteById(comment.getId());
post.setTotalCmnts(post.getTotalCmnts() - 1);
post.setComments(post.getComments().remove(comment));
System.out.println(comment.getId());
System.out.println("hello");
```

Additionally, I would add a custom `setComments()` method that actually updates `totalCmnts` based on the given parameter, otherwise, you might have inconsistent data. Also, the getter should return a copy of the list and not the list itself, otherwise, you might have some pretty nasty bugs because you change the list elsewhere and this change gets persisted without you noticing it.